# Best practices for Android + GWT + Server side + IDE

Tags: java, android, gwt, client-server

I am developing a Java app with [***Google App Engine***](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) and [***GWT***](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) (with RPC), using Eclipse and now I would like to start creating Android apps using existing shared code between projects.

I have several questions regarding **design patterns / best practices**:

1. **IDE** - I know now that developing Android apps in Eclipse has been deprecated for some time and is no longer possible (in favor of Android Studio), so what would the best practice be if I need to share code (models, java beans, utility methods) between server side (servlets), GWT and Android client side and to test?
2. **client-server communication** - for now, I am using GWT-RPC, but I've been meaning to change that. What would a good solution be to call actions on server side and use java beans (generic objects also)? 
   I don't mind using different communication types at the beginning (I can use RPC for GWT at start)

Some tutorials / links or other pointers would be very nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For IDE Eclipse does work. But I would recommend using IntelliJ (professional edition since this has GWT support)

Client-server communication. Just use JSON. I use jackson for both Android and GWT (gwt-jackson for GWT). I would strongly recommend to not use GWT-RPC. This will get you in all kind of difficult positions for Android. And since you need to make a JSON interface anyway, use it for both Android and GWT.